# Is there a simple way to subset 10 percent of train and test data using ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a structure of directories like this:

```
-root_dir----------------------------


--train
---dog   (contains 750 images of dogs)
---cat   (contains 750 images of cats)
---mouse (contains 750 images of mice)

--test
---dog   (contains 250 images of dogs)
---cat   (contains 250 images of cats)
---mouse (contains 250 images of mice)
```

That is how I load the data:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_data = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory='/root_dir/train/',
                                                target_size=(224, 224),
                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                seed=42)

test_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_data = test_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory='/root_dir/test/',
                                                target_size=(224, 224),
                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                seed=42)
```

It works fine.
`train_data` contains 750 images of each class.

However, I need to run fast experiments only on 10 percent of the data.
I need train_data_10_percent_subset that contains 75 randomly chosen images of each class.

**Is there a simple way with ImageDataGenerator to randomly choose 10 percent of the images in the train directory in each sub-folder?**

I need a generator that contains 75 images of each class from train subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=.1)
train_data = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(directory='/root_dir/train/',
                                                target_size=(224, 224),
                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                seed=42, subset='validation')
```

setting validation_split to .1 reserves 10 % of the data for validation. Setting subset='validation' will make the train_data have 10% of the training data

Comment: What is I don not set `subset='validation'` and set `validation_split=0.9'?